# Collect Email addresses

Tags: directory

I'm trying to collect all the email addresses from my Active Directory users. We don't use Exchange and when it was initially set up no emails were entered. Now we are trying to build a mailing list but we need to find a way to collect the emails when the users are logging in. They mainly log in using Remote Desktop.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: If you are not using Exchange, are the email addresses manually entered as attributes in Active Directory?

Comment: To add to what DanBig said, usually this is the "mail" attribute, is that not true for your users? If not, how do you envision this working, are you going to have your users fill out a webform or something?

Comment: I would rather have a log in script where the user would enter their emails.

Comment: How many users are you talking about? Depending on the count, likely more trouble to write something that will only ask the user once. Also, do you not have standardization? Username is jdoe, email is jdoe@domain.com

Comment: That's the problem there's no standardization.... We are talking at about 300 users. I wish this would of been planned better at the begining

Answer (score 3):

This is an organizational problem, not a technical one. From my reading of this, you're not referring to email addresses on a server that you administer - you have a population of about 300 users, they login via RDP, and you need to know their email addresses (that you don't manage.)

So ask them. How does your company normally interact with these users? Are they customers? Then treat them like customers - phone calls, etc. If they're members of a partner organization, ask your contact(s) at the partner.

Also, fix your new-user process so that this is collected at the beginning of the process.

You could write a login script asking them to enter their email address, as your comment suggests that you'd like. So, write one. If you have problems with that, post a better question here as a new question : what you tried and what failed.